# Oracle MAX() bug with NULLs CBO index fix leads to index limitation

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, indexing, cbo

**Update 1/31/2011**

I think I'm running against a DB limit. The GROUP BY expression
and all nondistinct aggregate functions may have exceeded a single
database block.
See http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/limits003.htm

**Original post:**

This is on Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Prod.

The following insert does not return the true MAX() values
if I have two records where the matchKey is the same, one
with a contributionP NULL value and another with a non-NULL value.
Sometimes, the value returned by MAX() is the NULL value.

```
INSERT /*+ APPEND */ INTO meCostingXPrePre(  
   matchKey                    ,  
   contributionP               ,  
   stimulusContributionP       ,  
   contributionC               ,  
   ageMultiplier               ,  
   rateTableIdP                ,  
   rateTableIdC                ,  
   accountNbrP                 ,  
   accountNbrC                 ,  
   commissionExpenseAccount    ,  
   commissionReceivableAccount ,  
   commissionType              ,  
   commission                  ,  
   pmPm                        ,  
   fee                         ,  
   planAgeGroupIdP             ,  
   planAgeGroupIdC             ,  
   rafP                        ,  
   rafC                        ,  
   nbrEmployeesRafP            ,  
   nbrEmployeesRafC            ,  
   contractId                  ,  
   basePlanId                  ,  
   groupOrPolicyNumber         ,  
   planCoverageDescription     ,  
   cobraGopn                   ,  
   cobraPcd                    ,  
   cobraCid                    ,  
   benefitId                   ,  
   insuranceStart              ,  
   insuranceEnd                ,  
   categoryId                  )  
   SELECT   
      matchKey                                                                    as matchKey                    ,  
      MAX(NVL(contributionP               ,0 ))                                   as contributionP               ,  
      MAX(NVL(stimulusContributionP       ,0 ))                                   as stimulusContributionP       ,  
      MAX(NVL(contributionC               ,0 ))                                   as contributionC               ,  
      MAX(NVL(ageMultiplier               ,0 ))                                   as ageMultiplier               ,  
      MAX(NVL(rateTableIdP                ,0 ))                                   as rateTableIdP                ,  
      MAX(NVL(rateTableIdC                ,0 ))                                   as rateTableIdC                ,  
      MAX(NVL(accountNbrP                 ,0 ))                                   as accountNbrP                 ,  
      MAX(NVL(accountNbrC                 ,0 ))                                   as accountNbrC                 ,  
      MAX(NVL(commissionExpenseAccount    ,0 ))                                   as commissionExpenseAccount    ,  
      MAX(NVL(commissionReceivableAccount ,0 ))                                   as commissionReceivableAccount ,  
      MAX(NVL(commissionType              ,0 ))                                   as commissionType              ,  
      MAX(NVL(commission                  ,0 ))                                   as commission                  ,  
      MAX(NVL(pmPm                        ,0 ))                                   as pmPm                        ,  
      MAX(NVL(fee                         ,0 ))                                   as fee                         ,  
      MAX(NVL(planAgeGroupIdP             ,0 ))                                   as planAgeGroupIdP             ,  
      MAX(NVL(planAgeGroupIdC             ,0 ))                                   as planAgeGroupIdC             ,  
      MAX(NVL(rafP                        ,0 ))                                   as rafP                        ,  
      MAX(NVL(rafC                        ,0 ))                                   as rafC                        ,  
      MAX(NVL(nbrEmployeesRafP            ,0 ))                                   as nbrEmployeesRafP            ,  
      MAX(NVL(nbrEmployeesRafC            ,0 ))                                   as nbrEmployeesRafC            ,  
      CASE WHEN MAX(contractId) IS NOT NULL AND  
                MIN(contractId) IS NOT NULL AND  
                MAX(contractId) != MIN(contractId) THEN  
         CASE WHEN MAX(contractId) = 'No Contract No' THEN  
            MIN(contractId)  
         WHEN MIN(contractId) = 'No Contract No' THEN  
            MAX(contractId)  
         ELSE  
            MAX(contractId)  
         END  
      ELSE  
         MAX(contractId)  
      END                                                                         as contractId                  ,  
      MAX(NVL(basePlanId                  ,0 ))                                   as basePlanId                  ,  
      CASE WHEN MAX(groupOrPolicyNumber) IS NOT NULL AND  
                MIN(groupOrPolicyNumber) IS NOT NULL AND  
                MAX(groupOrPolicyNumber) != MIN(groupOrPolicyNumber) THEN  
         CASE WHEN MAX(groupOrPolicyNumber) = 'No Contract No' THEN  
            MIN(groupOrPolicyNumber)  
         WHEN MIN(groupOrPolicyNumber) = 'No Contract No' THEN  
            MAX(groupOrPolicyNumber)  
         ELSE  
            MAX(groupOrPolicyNumber)  
         END  
      ELSE  
         MAX(groupOrPolicyNumber)  
      END                                                                         as groupOrPolicyNumber         ,  
      CASE WHEN MAX(planCoverageDescription) IS NOT NULL AND  
                MIN(planCoverageDescription) IS NOT NULL AND  
                MAX(planCoverageDescription) != MIN(planCoverageDescription) THEN  
         CASE WHEN MAX(planCoverageDescription) = 'No Contract No' THEN  
            MIN(planCoverageDescription)  
         WHEN MIN(planCoverageDescription) = 'No Contract No' THEN  
            MAX(planCoverageDescription)  
         ELSE  
            MAX(planCoverageDescription)  
         END  
      ELSE  
         MAX(planCoverageDescription)  
      END                                                                         as planCoverageDescription     ,  
      CASE WHEN MAX(cobraGopn) IS NOT NULL AND  
                MIN(cobraGopn) IS NOT NULL AND  
                MAX(cobraGopn) != MIN(cobraGopn) THEN  
         CASE WHEN MAX(cobraGopn) = 'No Contract No' THEN  
            MIN(cobraGopn)  
         WHEN MIN(cobraGopn) = 'No Contract No' THEN  
            MAX(cobraGopn)  
         ELSE  
            MAX(cobraGopn)  
         END  
      ELSE  
         MAX(cobraGopn)  
      END                                                                         as cobraGopn                   ,  
      CASE WHEN MAX(cobraPcd) IS NOT NULL AND  
                MIN(cobraPcd) IS NOT NULL AND  
                MAX(cobraPcd) != MIN(cobraPcd) THEN  
         CASE WHEN MAX(cobraPcd) = 'No Contract No' THEN  
            MIN(cobraPcd)  
         WHEN MIN(cobraPcd) = 'No Contract No' THEN  
            MAX(cobraPcd)  
         ELSE  
            MAX(cobraPcd)  
         END  
      ELSE  
         MAX(cobraPcd)  
      END                                                                         as cobraPcd                    ,  
      CASE WHEN MAX(cobraCid) IS NOT NULL AND  
                MIN(cobraCid) IS NOT NULL AND  
                MAX(cobraCid) != MIN(cobraCid) THEN  
         CASE WHEN MAX(cobraCid) = 'No Contract No' THEN  
            MIN(cobraCid)  
         WHEN MIN(cobraCid) = 'No Contract No' THEN  
            MAX(cobraCid)  
         ELSE  
            MAX(cobraCid)  
         END  
      ELSE  
         MAX(cobraCid)  
      END                                                                         as cobraCid                    ,  
      MAX(benefitId                           )                                   as benefitId                   ,  
      NULL                                                                        as insuranceStart              ,  
      NULL                                                                        as insuranceEnd                ,  
      NULL                                                                        as categoryId                    
   FROM meCostingXPrePrePre  
   GROUP BY matchKey;
```

If I build an index as follows and give a CBO hint

```
CREATE INDEX C$MECOSTINGXPREPREPRE$MULTI0 ON MECOSTINGXPREPREPRE
(MATCHKEY, CONTRIBUTIONP, STIMULUSCONTRIBUTIONP, CONTRIBUTIONC, AGEMULTIPLIER, 
RATETABLEIDP, RATETABLEIDC, ACCOUNTNBRP, ACCOUNTNBRC, COMMISSIONEXPENSEACCOUNT, 
COMMISSIONRECEIVABLEACCOUNT, COMMISSIONTYPE, COMMISSION, PMPM, FEE, 
PLANAGEGROUPIDP, PLANAGEGROUPIDC, RAFP, RAFC, 
NBREMPLOYEESRAFP, NBREMPLOYEESRAFC, CONTRACTID, BASEPLANID, GROUPORPOLICYNUMBER, 
PLANCOVERAGEDESCRIPTION, COBRAGOPN, COBRAPCD, COBRACID, BENEFITID)
NOLOGGING
TABLESPACE INDX
NOPARALLEL;

INSERT /*+ APPEND */ INTO meCostingXPrePre(
   ...)
   SELECT /*+ INDEX(meCostingXPrePrePre c$mecostingxpreprepre$multi0) */
      ...
   FROM meCostingXPrePrePre
   GROUP BY matchKey;
```

This gets MAX() to behave correctly.

I need to add 15 extra columns and change the index

Small problem

```
CREATE INDEX C$MECOSTINGXPREPREPRE$MULTI0 ON MECOSTINGXPREPREPRE
(MATCHKEY, CONTRIBUTIONP, STIMULUSCONTRIBUTIONP, CONTRIBUTIONC, AGEMULTIPLIER, 
RATETABLEIDP, RATETABLEIDC, ACCOUNTNBRP, ACCOUNTNBRC, COMMISSIONEXPENSEACCOUNT, 
COMMISSIONRECEIVABLEACCOUNT, COMMISSIONTYPE, COMMISSION, PMPM, FEE, 
PLANAGEGROUPIDP, PLANAGEGROUPIDC, ADDRESSONEP, ADDRESSONEC, ADDRESSTWOP, 
ADDRESSTWOC, CITYP, CITYC, STATEP, STATEC, ZIPFULLP, ZIPFULLC, RAFP, RAFC, 
NBREMPLOYEESRAFP, NBREMPLOYEESRAFC, CONTRACTID, BASEPLANID, GROUPORPOLICYNUMBER, 
PLANCOVERAGEDESCRIPTION, COBRAGOPN, COBRAPCD, COBRACID, BENEFITID)
NOLOGGING
TABLESPACE INDX
NOPARALLEL;
```

gives
ORA-01793: maximum number of index columns is 32

First MAX() does not work with large column sets and second, the index+CBO patch
leads to index limitation.

Any suggestions?

Comment: "I need to add 15 extra columns" -- These are words that should almost nev...no...never be spoken. There's an issue with your design if you're *adding fifteen columns to a table that's already in use*. If you have 15 columns *at all*, you should consider looking at where you can normalize.

Comment: What is MAX(NVL(cobraPcd,'')) supposed to do? In Oracle, '' is the same as NULL, so NVL(cobraPcd,'') is the same as _cobraPcd_. And MAX handles NULL values anyway.

Comment: Is this bug listed on Metalink? Can you come up with a *simple* (meaning not so many columns) test case to reproduce it?

Comment: All the MAX(NVL(___,'')) type lines were something I tried thinking the Oracle MAX() bug would be resolved. For all intents and purposes, '' == NULL.  I've made that change now, the NVL(__,'') should not have been included above.

Comment: Normalization in a stored procedure context caused joins to get completely out of control.  I agree with normalization for source and destination tables, however, normalization is not always the perfect solution for every context.

Comment: Can contributionP ever be negative?

Comment: I think I'm running against a DB limit.  The GROUP BY expression and all nondistinct aggregate functions may have exceeded a single database block. See http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/limits003.htm

Comment: please revisit the decision to not normalize properly.

Comment: @Adam Robinson I will normalize. I need to get 80 columns of data out of the stored proc by line 10600. I will work my way backward. Basically, every composite key needs to be referenced by a unique id column as that data needs to be reported by the end of the stored proc. I have not introduced referential integrity constraints as they would slow down the stored proc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, splitting the work in half will get me what I need:

```
INSERT /*+ APPEND */ INTO meCostingXPrePreFirstHalf(  
   matchKey                    ,  
   contributionP               ,  
   stimulusContributionP       ,  
   contributionC               ,  
   ageMultiplier               ,  
   rateTableIdP                ,  
   rateTableIdC                ,  
   accountNbrP                 ,  
   accountNbrC                 ,  
   commissionExpenseAccount    ,  
   commissionReceivableAccount ,  
   commissionType              ,  
   commission                  ,  
   pmPm                        ,  
   fee                         ,  
   planAgeGroupIdP             ,  
   planAgeGroupIdC             )  
   SELECT   
      matchKey                                  as matchKey                    ,  
      MAX(NVL(contributionP               ,0 )) as contributionP               ,  
      MAX(NVL(stimulusContributionP       ,0 )) as stimulusContributionP       ,  
      MAX(NVL(contributionC               ,0 )) as contributionC               ,  
      MAX(NVL(ageMultiplier               ,0 )) as ageMultiplier               ,  
      MAX(NVL(rateTableIdP                ,0 )) as rateTableIdP                ,  
      MAX(NVL(rateTableIdC                ,0 )) as rateTableIdC                ,  
      MAX(NVL(accountNbrP                 ,0 )) as accountNbrP                 ,  
      MAX(NVL(accountNbrC                 ,0 )) as accountNbrC                 ,  
      MAX(NVL(commissionExpenseAccount    ,0 )) as commissionExpenseAccount    ,  
      MAX(NVL(commissionReceivableAccount ,0 )) as commissionReceivableAccount ,  
      MAX(NVL(commissionType              ,0 )) as commissionType              ,  
      MAX(NVL(commission                  ,0 )) as commission                  ,  
      MAX(NVL(pmPm                        ,0 )) as pmPm                        ,  
      MAX(NVL(fee                         ,0 )) as fee                         ,  
      MAX(NVL(planAgeGroupIdP             ,0 )) as planAgeGroupIdP             ,  
      MAX(NVL(planAgeGroupIdC             ,0 )) as planAgeGroupIdC                
   FROM meCostingXPrePrePre  
   GROUP BY matchKey;  
/* No commit yet. */

INSERT /*+ APPEND */ INTO meCostingXPrePreOtherHalf(  
   matchKey                    ,  
   rafP                        ,  
   rafC                        ,  
   nbrEmployeesRafP            ,  
   nbrEmployeesRafC            ,  
   contractId                  ,  
   basePlanId                  ,  
   groupOrPolicyNumber         ,  
   planCoverageDescription     ,  
   cobraGopn                   ,  
   cobraPcd                    ,  
   cobraCid                    ,  
   benefitId                   ,  
   insuranceStart              ,  
   insuranceEnd                ,  
   categoryId                  )  
   SELECT  
      matchKey                                                                    as matchKey                    ,  
      MAX(NVL(rafP                        ,0 ))                                   as rafP                        ,  
      MAX(NVL(rafC                        ,0 ))                                   as rafC                        ,  
      MAX(NVL(nbrEmployeesRafP            ,0 ))                                   as nbrEmployeesRafP            ,  
      MAX(NVL(nbrEmployeesRafC            ,0 ))                                   as nbrEmployeesRafC            ,  
      CASE WHEN MAX(contractId) IS NOT NULL AND  
                MIN(contractId) IS NOT NULL AND  
                MAX(contractId) != MIN(contractId) THEN  
         CASE WHEN MAX(contractId) = 'No Contract No' THEN  
            MIN(contractId)  
         WHEN MIN(contractId) = 'No Contract No' THEN  
            MAX(contractId)  
         ELSE  
            MAX(contractId)  
         END  
      ELSE  
         MAX(contractId)  
      END                                                                         as contractId                  ,  
      MAX(NVL(basePlanId                  ,0 ))                                   as basePlanId                  ,  
      CASE WHEN MAX(groupOrPolicyNumber) IS NOT NULL AND  
                MIN(groupOrPolicyNumber) IS NOT NULL AND  
                MAX(groupOrPolicyNumber) != MIN(groupOrPolicyNumber) THEN  
         CASE WHEN MAX(groupOrPolicyNumber) = 'No Contract No' THEN  
            MIN(groupOrPolicyNumber)  
         WHEN MIN(groupOrPolicyNumber) = 'No Contract No' THEN  
            MAX(groupOrPolicyNumber)  
         ELSE  
            MAX(groupOrPolicyNumber)  
         END  
      ELSE  
         MAX(groupOrPolicyNumber)  
      END                                                                         as groupOrPolicyNumber         ,  
      CASE WHEN MAX(planCoverageDescription) IS NOT NULL AND  
                MIN(planCoverageDescription) IS NOT NULL AND  
                MAX(planCoverageDescription) != MIN(planCoverageDescription) THEN  
         CASE WHEN MAX(planCoverageDescription) = 'No Contract No' THEN  
            MIN(planCoverageDescription)  
         WHEN MIN(planCoverageDescription) = 'No Contract No' THEN  
            MAX(planCoverageDescription)  
         ELSE  
            MAX(planCoverageDescription)  
         END  
      ELSE  
         MAX(planCoverageDescription)  
      END                                                                         as planCoverageDescription     ,  
      CASE WHEN MAX(cobraGopn) IS NOT NULL AND  
                MIN(cobraGopn) IS NOT NULL AND  
                MAX(cobraGopn) != MIN(cobraGopn) THEN  
         CASE WHEN MAX(cobraGopn) = 'No Contract No' THEN  
            MIN(cobraGopn)  
         WHEN MIN(cobraGopn) = 'No Contract No' THEN  
            MAX(cobraGopn)  
         ELSE  
            MAX(cobraGopn)  
         END  
      ELSE  
         MAX(cobraGopn)  
      END                                                                         as cobraGopn                   ,  
      CASE WHEN MAX(cobraPcd) IS NOT NULL AND  
                MIN(cobraPcd) IS NOT NULL AND  
                MAX(cobraPcd) != MIN(cobraPcd) THEN  
         CASE WHEN MAX(cobraPcd) = 'No Contract No' THEN  
            MIN(cobraPcd)  
         WHEN MIN(cobraPcd) = 'No Contract No' THEN  
            MAX(cobraPcd)  
         ELSE  
            MAX(cobraPcd)  
         END  
      ELSE  
         MAX(cobraPcd)  
      END                                                                         as cobraPcd                    ,  
      CASE WHEN MAX(cobraCid) IS NOT NULL AND  
                MIN(cobraCid) IS NOT NULL AND  
                MAX(cobraCid) != MIN(cobraCid) THEN  
         CASE WHEN MAX(cobraCid) = 'No Contract No' THEN  
            MIN(cobraCid)  
         WHEN MIN(cobraCid) = 'No Contract No' THEN  
            MAX(cobraCid)  
         ELSE  
            MAX(cobraCid)  
         END  
      ELSE  
         MAX(cobraCid)  
      END                                                                         as cobraCid                    ,  
      MAX(benefitId                           )                                   as benefitId                      
   FROM meCostingXPrePrePre  
   GROUP BY matchKey;  
/* No commit yet. */

INSERT /*+ APPEND */ INTO meCostingXPrePre(  
   matchKey                    ,  
   contributionP               ,  
   stimulusContributionP       ,  
   contributionC               ,  
   ageMultiplier               ,  
   rateTableIdP                ,  
   rateTableIdC                ,  
   accountNbrP                 ,  
   accountNbrC                 ,  
   commissionExpenseAccount    ,  
   commissionReceivableAccount ,  
   commissionType              ,  
   commission                  ,  
   pmPm                        ,  
   fee                         ,  
   planAgeGroupIdP             ,  
   planAgeGroupIdC             ,  
   rafP                        ,  
   rafC                        ,  
   nbrEmployeesRafP            ,  
   nbrEmployeesRafC            ,  
   contractId                  ,  
   basePlanId                  ,  
   groupOrPolicyNumber         ,  
   planCoverageDescription     ,  
   cobraGopn                   ,  
   cobraPcd                    ,  
   cobraCid                    ,  
   benefitId                   ,  
   insuranceStart              ,  
   insuranceEnd                ,  
   categoryId                  )  
   SELECT 
      f.matchKey                    as matchKey                    ,  
      f.contributionP               as contributionP               ,  
      f.stimulusContributionP       as stimulusContributionP       ,  
      f.contributionC               as contributionC               ,  
      f.ageMultiplier               as ageMultiplier               ,  
      f.rateTableIdP                as rateTableIdP                ,  
      f.rateTableIdC                as rateTableIdC                ,  
      f.accountNbrP                 as accountNbrP                 ,  
      f.accountNbrC                 as accountNbrC                 ,  
      f.commissionExpenseAccount    as commissionExpenseAccount    ,  
      f.commissionReceivableAccount as commissionReceivableAccount ,  
      f.commissionType              as commissionType              ,  
      f.commission                  as commission                  ,  
      f.pmPm                        as pmPm                        ,  
      f.fee                         as fee                         ,  
      f.planAgeGroupIdP             as planAgeGroupIdP             ,  
      f.planAgeGroupIdC             as planAgeGroupIdC             ,  
      o.rafP                        as rafP                        ,  
      o.rafC                        as rafC                        ,  
      o.nbrEmployeesRafP            as nbrEmployeesRafP            ,  
      o.nbrEmployeesRafC            as nbrEmployeesRafC            ,  
      o.contractId                  as contractId                  ,  
      o.basePlanId                  as basePlanId                  ,  
      o.groupOrPolicyNumber         as groupOrPolicyNumber         ,  
      o.planCoverageDescription     as planCoverageDescription     ,  
      o.cobraGopn                   as cobraGopn                   ,  
      o.cobraPcd                    as cobraPcd                    ,  
      o.cobraCid                    as cobraCid                    ,  
      o.benefitId                   as benefitId                   ,  
      o.insuranceStart              as insuranceStart              ,  
      o.insuranceEnd                as insuranceEnd                ,  
      o.categoryId                  as categoryId                  ,  
      NULL                          as insuranceStart              ,  
      NULL                          as insuranceEnd                ,  
      NULL                          as categoryId                     
   FROM  
      meCostingXPrePreFirstHalf f  
         INNER JOIN meCostingXPrePreOtherHalf o  
         ON f.matchKey = o.matchKey;  
/* Now it is safe to commit. */
COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're getting incorrect results, that's obviously an Oracle bug.  Have you logged a support request with Oracle Support and/or identified the bug you're hitting (which I'm guessing is where the workaround comes from)?

If you are using 10.2.0.1, have you tried applying the latest patchset (most likely 10.2.0.4)?  There are a number of bug fixes between the initial 10.2 release and the terminal 10.2 release.  If this is a bug that Oracle has fixed, there may also be a one-off patch, though that patch likely requires the latest patchset to be installed.

Comment: Sounds good in a perfect world. However Oracle's tech support is not very responsive and no-one on the forums has much to say except upgrade or patch.

Comment: @Dragos - Is there a reason that you haven't applied the latest patchset?  People that want to stick with older releases generally do so because they perceive them as more stable.  But they're more stable because there have been a number of patchsets released that fix various bugs.  Running an older release unpatched seems very odd to me.  Applying the patchset will also rule out a host of bugs and make troubleshooting easier.

Comment: @Justin - I'll download and add the patch set.

Comment: I think you're not getting much response because most people have never seen a query done that way.  An NVL inside of a MAX doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: JOTN, please see my first comment following parent question.

Comment: @Justin - The latest patch will not solve the problem.  I think I'm running against a DB limitation here (the patched 10g and 11g have the same limitation)

Comment: @Dragos - Do you have some sample data that causes the problem to reproduce reliably?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried writing the SELECT part of the query like this. It should return the same result.

It works in two steps: First it calculates the required minimum and maximum values and then it does some NULL value replacement. (Your CASE statements seem to be overly complex since you haven't considered that an empty string and NULL are the same in Oracle.)

I'd be very intersted to know if the inner SELECT has already wrong maximum result.

```
SELECT   
  matchKey                                                               as matchKey                    ,  
  NVL(contributionP               ,0 )                                   as contributionP               ,  
  NVL(stimulusContributionP       ,0 )                                   as stimulusContributionP       ,  
  NVL(contributionC               ,0 )                                   as contributionC               ,  
  NVL(ageMultiplier               ,0 )                                   as ageMultiplier               ,  
  NVL(rateTableIdP                ,0 )                                   as rateTableIdP                ,  
  NVL(rateTableIdC                ,0 )                                   as rateTableIdC                ,  
  NVL(accountNbrP                 ,0 )                                   as accountNbrP                 ,  
  NVL(accountNbrC                 ,0 )                                   as accountNbrC                 ,  
  NVL(commissionExpenseAccount    ,0 )                                   as commissionExpenseAccount    ,  
  NVL(commissionReceivableAccount ,0 )                                   as commissionReceivableAccount ,  
  NVL(commissionType              ,0 )                                   as commissionType              ,  
  NVL(commission                  ,0 )                                   as commission                  ,  
  NVL(pmPm                        ,0 )                                   as pmPm                        ,  
  NVL(fee                         ,0 )                                   as fee                         ,  
  NVL(planAgeGroupIdP             ,0 )                                   as planAgeGroupIdP             ,  
  NVL(planAgeGroupIdC             ,0 )                                   as planAgeGroupIdC             ,  
  NVL(rafP                        ,0 )                                   as rafP                        ,  
  NVL(rafC                        ,0 )                                   as rafC                        ,  
  NVL(nbrEmployeesRafP            ,0 )                                   as nbrEmployeesRafP            ,  
  NVL(nbrEmployeesRafC            ,0 )                                   as nbrEmployeesRafC            ,  
  CASE
    WHEN maxContractId = 'No Contract No' THEN minContractId
    ELSE maxContractId
  END                                                                    as contractId                  ,
  NVL(basePlanId                  ,0 )                                   as basePlanId                  ,  
  CASE
    WHEN maxGroupOrPolicyNumber = 'No Contract No' THEN minGroupOrPolicyNumber
    ELSE maxGroupOrPolicyNumber
  END                                                                    as groupOrPolicyNumber         ,
  CASE
    WHEN maxPlanCoverageDescription = 'No Contract No' THEN minPlanCoverageDescription
    ELSE maxPlanCoverageDescription
  END                                                                    as planCoverageDescription     ,
  CASE
    WHEN maxCobraGopn = 'No Contract No' THEN minCobraGopn
    ELSE maxCobraGopn
  END                                                                    as cobraGopn                   ,
  CASE
    WHEN maxCobraPcd = 'No Contract No' THEN minCobraPcd
    ELSE maxCobraPcd
  END                                                                    as cobraPcd                    ,
  CASE
    WHEN maxCobraCid = 'No Contract No' THEN minCobraCid
    ELSE maxCobraCid
  END                                                                    as cobraCid                    ,
  benefitId                                                              as benefitId                   ,  
  NULL                                                                   as insuranceStart              ,  
  NULL                                                                   as insuranceEnd                ,  
  NULL                                                                   as categoryId                    
FROM (   
  SELECT
        matchKey                                                            as matchKey                    ,  
        MAX(contributionP               )                                   as contributionP               ,  
        MAX(stimulusContributionP       )                                   as stimulusContributionP       ,  
        MAX(contributionC               )                                   as contributionC               ,  
        MAX(ageMultiplier               )                                   as ageMultiplier               ,  
        MAX(rateTableIdP                )                                   as rateTableIdP                ,  
        MAX(rateTableIdC                )                                   as rateTableIdC                ,  
        MAX(accountNbrP                 )                                   as accountNbrP                 ,  
        MAX(accountNbrC                 )                                   as accountNbrC                 ,  
        MAX(commissionExpenseAccount    )                                   as commissionExpenseAccount    ,  
        MAX(commissionReceivableAccount )                                   as commissionReceivableAccount ,  
        MAX(commissionType              )                                   as commissionType              ,  
        MAX(commission                  )                                   as commission                  ,  
        MAX(pmPm                        )                                   as pmPm                        ,  
        MAX(fee                         )                                   as fee                         ,  
        MAX(planAgeGroupIdP             )                                   as planAgeGroupIdP             ,  
        MAX(planAgeGroupIdC             )                                   as planAgeGroupIdC             ,  
        MAX(rafP                        )                                   as rafP                        ,  
        MAX(rafC                        )                                   as rafC                        ,  
        MAX(nbrEmployeesRafP            )                                   as nbrEmployeesRafP            ,  
        MAX(nbrEmployeesRafC            )                                   as nbrEmployeesRafC            ,  
        MIN(contractId                  )                                   as minContractId               ,  
        MAX(contractId                  )                                   as maxContractId               ,  
        MAX(basePlanId                  )                                   as basePlanId                  ,  
        MIN(groupOrPolicyNumber         )                                   as minGroupOrPolicyNumber      ,  
        MAX(groupOrPolicyNumber         )                                   as maxGroupOrPolicyNumber      ,  
        MIN(planCoverageDescription     )                                   as minPlanCoverageDescription  ,  
        MAX(planCoverageDescription     )                                   as maxPlanCoverageDescription  ,  
        MIN(cobraGopn                   )                                   as minCobraGopn                ,  
        MAX(cobraGopn                   )                                   as maxCobraGopn                ,  
        MIN(cobraPcd                    )                                   as mincobraPcd                 ,  
        MAX(cobraPcd                    )                                   as maxcobraPcd                 ,  
        MIN(cobraCid                    )                                   as minCobraCid                 ,  
        MAX(cobraCid                    )                                   as maxCobraCid                 ,  
        MAX(benefitId                   )                                   as benefitId                   
     FROM meCostingXPrePrePre  
     GROUP BY matchKey
);
```

Comment: Perhaps the GROUP BY expression and all nondistinct aggregate functions may have exceeded a single database block. See http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/limits003.htm

Comment: The above did not work.  The GROUP BY coupled with twice the number of aggregate functions goes well over 1 DB block in my environment.